# C++ недопустимое количество параметров в команде xcopy

Tags: c++, cmd, bat

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("color 02");
    system("xcopy 'C:\text.txt' 'F:\hack ' /E");
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: в консоль выдает "недопустимое число параметров"

Answer (score 5):

Думаю, вы не учли, что обратный слеш внутри строковых литералов имеет особое значение. Либо заэкранируйте их:

```
"xcopy 'C:\\text.txt' 'F:\\hack ' /E"
```

либо используйте «сырые» литералы:

```
R"(xcopy 'C:\text.txt' 'F:\hack ' /E)"
```

---

Теперь, с точки зрения командного интерпретатора, вам нужно убрать одинарные кавычки, заменив их на двойные, и убрать лишний параметр `/E` (т. к. вы копируете один файл). Поскольку двойные кавычки нужно экранировать, получится вот что:

```
"xcopy \"D:\\text.txt\" \"D:\\hack\""
```

или

```
R"(xcopy "D:\text.txt" "D:\hack")"
```

Comment: все равно не работает ((

Comment: @Abyx: Странно, а почему не ок? Или вы имеете в виду с точки зрения командного интерпретатора?

Comment: @Abyx: Я попробовал, и правда не работают.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
 system("xcopy C:\\text.txt F:\\hack /E");
```

Comment: просто лучший!!!!